# How to update server property on updating client property

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, inotifypropertychanged

I have two equal classes on both sides of WCF communication:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

One client's class update I need to update the service's class.
I can implement a WCF service with methods:

```
public interface IUserInfoUpdateContract
{
   void UpdateFirstName(string value);
   void UpdateLastName(string value);
   void UpdateAge(string value);
   ...
}
```

But, is there an alternative way how I can update properties dynamically?
E.g.:

```
public interface IUserInfoUpdate
{
   void UpdateProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue);
}
```

Usage on client side:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get { return _firstName; }
        set 
        { 
            _firstName = value;
            wcfClient.UpdateProperty(nameof(FirstName), FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have any options how to dynamically update the properties on service side without Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use reflection you can do the following. Add inner `Dictionary` to `UserInfo` holds all properties values and then it will be possible to reference these values by property name `string`

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            object value;
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(FirstName), out value) ? (string)value : null;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[nameof(FirstName)] = value;
        }
    }


    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            object value;
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(LastName), out value) ? (string)value : null;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[nameof(LastName)] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            object value;
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(Age), out value) ? (int)value : 0;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[nameof(Age)] = value;
        }
    }

    public object this[string property]
    {
        set
        {
            //todo: validation if needed
            _dictionary[property] = value;
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
var info = new UserInfo();
info.FirstName = "hello";
info["LastName"] = "Last";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to apply to  UserInfo instead of any type, you could use if else, so that you only need one method in your server side.

```
 public void UpdateProperty(string propertyName,object propertyValue)
    {
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(); // use your userInfo
        if(propertyName == "FirstName")
        {
            userInfo.FirstName = propertyValue as string;
        }
        if(propertyName == "Age")
        {
            userInfo.Age = (int)propertyValue;
        }
    }
```